# Hatching DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have WinForms project in C# that it has DataGridView control.

I'm looking for something to express that the DataGridView cell will not be valued.

In excel app hatching is a good way for that purpose. So I want to hatch DataGridView cell similar excel cell as you see in picture below.

[image]

I guess I should use CellPainting event. But I couldn't achieve that. If anyone has done something similar to this? Thanx.

Comment: You can handle [CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event and then fill the cell using a [HatchBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle [CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event and then fill the cell using a [HatchBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). You also need to invalidate the control in the event of scroll and enable double buffering to prevent flicker.

Here is an example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("C1");
    dt.Columns.Add("C2");
    dt.Columns.Add("C3");
    dt.Rows.Add("X", "X", "O");
    dt.Rows.Add("X", DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value);
    dt.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.CellPainting += DataGridView1_CellPainting;
    dataGridView1.Scroll += (_, __) => dataGridView1.Invalidate();
    dataGridView1.GetType().GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(dataGridView1, true);
}
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;
    if(e.Value==DBNull.Value)
    {
        using(var b= new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.ForwardDiagonal,
            Color.Black, Color.White))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.CellBounds);
            e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & 
                ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Above example is using `ForwardDiagonal` as [HatchStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchstyle?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

In above example, I've filled the background of the cells which have `DBNull.Value` as their value. You can use any other condition, for example based on having the cell as ReadOnly.

Here is the screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: It is perfectly worked. Thanks for your clear and detailed explanations.